# How to prevent Math.max() return NaN?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a function which returns the maximum number from an array, but it keeps returning `NaN`.

How can I prevent NaN and return the wanted result ?

```
var thenum = [5,3,678,213];

function max(num){
    console.log(Math.max(num));
}

max(thenum);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why this is happening is that `Math.max` calculates the maximum out of its parameters. And seen as the first parameter is an Array it returns NaN.

You now have **2 options** (depending on your environment or preference):

#### ES6 (with spread syntax)

You can spread the array to the params of the function.

```
const thenum = [5, 3, 678, 213];

console.log(Math.max(...thenum));
```

More on [the spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

And [here](https://jsfiddle.net/k7zsbfd3/1/) is a jsFiddle with this example.

---

#### ES5 (without spread syntax)

Or, you can call it using the `apply` method which allows you to call functions and send the parameters for them within an array.

What you want is to apply the `Math.max` function, like so:

```
var thenum = [5, 3, 678, 213];

function max(num){
    return Math.max.apply(null, num);
}

console.log(max(thenum));
```

You can also make it a method and attach it to the Array prototype. This way you can use it easier and cleaner (**overwriting the prototype is dangerous and you should probably avoid it** - [Read more about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice)). Like so:

```
Array.prototype.max = function () {
    return Math.max.apply(null, this);
};
console.log([5, 3, 678, 213].max());
```

More on [the apply method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

And [here](https://jsfiddle.net/k7zsbfd3/1/) is a jsFiddle with both

Comment: The answer should be updated to add the spread operator solutoin

Comment: @CristianTraìna Thanks for the heads up. Edited the post :)

Answer (score 1):

try this one.  `Math.max.apply(Math,thenum)`

```
var thenum = [5,3,678,213];

function max(num){
    console.log(Math.max.apply(Math,thenum));
}
```

> result: 678

Answer (score 1):

The Math.max() method doesn't allow you to pass in an array. So for Array you have to do using Function.prototype.apply(), e.g.

```
Math.max.apply(null, Array);
```

Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Answer (score 0):

```
var p = [35,2,65,7,8,9,12,121,33,99];

Array.prototype.max = function() {
  return Math.max.apply(null, this);
};

Array.prototype.min = function() {
  return Math.min.apply(null, this);
};


alert("Max value is: "+p.max()+"\nMin value is: "+ p.min());
```

> **[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nikhilagarwal530/np9L66bv/)**